# Fortran read function does not read the last value

Tags: fortran

I have a input file (filename: L0analysis) like below

```
......           !headers
3 2.1 2.4 2.5    !ntfmr rcut(1) rcut(2) rcut(3)
......           !other data
```

The index i in rcut(i) is determined by ntfmr

in my program,

```
......
ncrit=55
open(ncrit,file='Lanalysis')
......!(read the headers. skipped here)
read(ncrit,*) ntfmr, (rcut(i),i=1,ntfmr)
do i=1,ntfmr            ! # of network formers and their cutoffs
  rcut2(i)=rcut(i)*rcut(i)
  write(*,*)'ntfmr',ntfmr,'i=',i,rcut(i)  
enddo
.......
.......
```

My output is

> ntfmr           3 i=           1   2.10000000000000
>
> ntfmr           3 i=           2   2.40000000000000
>
> ntfmr           3 i=           3   4.41000000000000

I tried to initialize rcut(i)=0. It does not work. I cannot find any place to change this value.
I am unable to figure it out what is going wrong. Any suggestion or comment will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I fixed some formatting in your post, check its correct. What you have there looks fine, and there is no need to initialize `rcut`.  Whatever is going on lies elsewhere in the code (likely some array declared incorrectly).

Comment: Show the declarations for `rcut`.  My guess is that its size is less than three, so the calculation of `rcut2` is trampling memory - the displayed value of `rcut(3)` is the expected value of `rcut2(1)`.  Realistically, for this sort of problem you must come up with a minimum compilable example, otherwise you are likely just wasting people's time.

Comment: I second the need for a [mcve].  In addition to the array, you talk about the input file `L0analysis` but the `open` statement refers to `file='Lanalysis'`.

Comment: @lanH Thank you so much! i read this program written by somebody. Yes, you are right. Following your suggestion, I checked the head file. This array was defined as rcut(mxntfmr) where the mxntfmr was defined in parameter which I did not pay attention to.

Comment: @agentp Thank you! You are right.

Comment: @francescalus Thank you for your pointing out the error. The program is correct. I made a mistake when I edited my question.